# If/else statement, else is printing every time

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a code and every time I run it, the else statement always prints with the if statement. I've looked it over a ton and I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgAbbreviation {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userText = "";

      System.out.println("Input an abbreviation: ");
      userText = scnr.nextLine();

      if (userText.equals("LOL")) {
         System.out.println("laughing out loud");
      }

      if (userText.equals("IDK")) {
         System.out.println("I don't know");
      }

      if (userText.equals("BFF")) {
         System.out.println("best friends forever");
      }

      if (userText.equals("IMHO")) {
         System.out.println("in my humble opinion");
      }

      if (userText.equals("TMI")) {
         System.out.println("too much information");
      }

      else {
         System.out.println("Unknown");
      }

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need `else if` for most of those blocks (not the first one)

Comment: A [`switch`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/614/switch-statement#t=201703261638592950685) would be a great choice.

Answer (score 1):

It is checking every `if` statement and if not `userText.equals("TMI")`, it'll always print `Unknown`.

Solution is to put `else if`, so it'll check other `if`s only if this `if`'s condition is false:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgAbbreviation {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userText = "";

      System.out.println("Input an abbreviation: ");
      userText = scnr.nextLine();

      if (userText.equals("LOL")) {
         System.out.println("laughing out loud");
      }else if (userText.equals("IDK")) {
         System.out.println("I don't know");
      }else if (userText.equals("BFF")) {
         System.out.println("best friends forever");
      }else if (userText.equals("IMHO")) {
         System.out.println("in my humble opinion");
      }else if (userText.equals("TMI")) {
         System.out.println("too much information");
      }else {
         System.out.println("Unknown");
      }

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about trying else if, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at this part of the code for example:

```
  if (userText.equals("IMHO")) {
     System.out.println("in my humble opinion");
  }

  if (userText.equals("TMI")) {
     System.out.println("too much information");
  }

  else {
     System.out.println("Unknown");
  }
```

and let's suppose your `userText` is "TEST"

`first if` statement is false, `second` is false also; then `else` is entered.

You *need* to chain via `if else` and not `if if`

Answer (score 0):

The else statement will execute, because is linked only to the last if.If the last if is false (input is not "TMI"), it will execute.
Make the ifs as else if (except the first one, offcourse)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgAbbreviation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userText = "";

System.out.println("Input an abbreviation: ");
userText = scnr.nextLine();

if (userText.equals("LOL")) 
     System.out.println("laughing out loud");

else if (userText.equals("IDK")) 
     System.out.println("I don't know");

else if (userText.equals("BFF")) 
     System.out.println("best friends forever");

else if (userText.equals("IMHO")) 
     System.out.println("in my humble opinion");

else if (userText.equals("TMI")) 
     System.out.println("too much information");

else 
     System.out.println("Unknown");

  return;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You are only applying the `else` to the last `if` statement. If you wanted to fix it, you could use an `else if` for each subsequent if statement after the initial. Using a switch statement would be a potential solution but see below for something a little more efficient that is capable of being somewhat more extensible.

Alternatively you could try a solution that improves something known as *cyclomatic complexity*. If you utilise a map, you could use the `getOrDefault` method to do what you're doing with your `if else` combinations.

See [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

See below: -

```
final Map<String,String> foo = new HashMap<>();
foo.put ("LOL", "Laughing out loud");
foo.put ("IDK", "I don't know");
foo.put ("BFF", "best friends forever");
// and so on for the other values
```

Then you can use the following in place of your `if/else`

```
final String value = foo.getOrDefault(userText, "Unknown");
System.out.println (value);
```

The else case would then be the default case for the key not being in the map.

The reason I think this is a better solution is because you're basically creating a dictionary and a map is best suited for this instead of a series of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

using switch it can simply know which to output based on the inputted String by the user

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
          String userText = "";

          System.out.println("Input an abbreviation: ");
          userText = scnr.nextLine();
          //test the userText at switch structure
         switch(userText)
         {
                     //if LOL is type by the User
             case "LOL":
                System.out.println("laughing out loud");
                 break;
        //if IDK is type by the User     
             case "IDK":
             System.out.println("I don't know");
                 break;
                     //if BFF is type by the User
             case "BFF":
             System.out.println("best friends forever");
                 break;
             //if IMHO is type by the User
             case "IMHO":
             System.out.println("in my humble opinion");
                 break;
             //if TMI is type by the User
             case "TMI": 
             System.out.println("too much information");
                 break;
             //if any other entered String
             default:
             System.out.println("Unknown");
             break;


         }


        }
```

Comment: A code block with two words is a terrible answer. Please explain what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: Yes pretty much if he doesn't know switch structure